# How to use GDAL/python to fill the no data value

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am using GDAL tool to merge many geotiffs and get the following result:[image]

how to fill the no data and change the no data value to 1?

Comment: From the docs http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html (I assume you're using merge although not stated in your question) you should be able to use -init 1 -n 1 -a_nodata 1 to set various fill/nodata options.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, i convert this geotiff to ascii file first and change the values, then convert ascii file back to geotiff.

Comment: `gdal_translate` is able to set a NODATA value without the need to convert to another format. It is also accessible within the QGIS `Raster` menu.